# Have variable instead of hardcoded value in react built app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I'm building an app that will be deployed through Docker containers and so some part of my code will have to change, mainly IPs

Currently I've been using a config file, but I just realised that when I was building my app everything was hardcoded inside which is clearly not what I want

I've been looking through solutions but I can't seem to find exactly what I'm trying to do, so is it even possible

I'm using Vite if that helps.
TL;DR : Need to change the server IP in the code/Make it import from an outside source instead of the hardcoded parts when built

Comment: You should use environment variables

Comment: Doesn’t fix the problem, when built the env will stay the same even if changed after. I don’t want to have to rebuild the app every time I need to deploy it somewhere else.

Comment: *I don’t want to have to rebuild the app every time I need to deploy it somewhere else* - but this is how it's done everywhere. Usually built process is automated

Comment: Hmm I see, what I was trying to make is a easy deploy by just having a single container where I could only have to modify a single file inside. Maybe I should just have it built inside the dockerfile and change the env there ? So I can have an automated rebuild every time or something like that ?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers

Comment: I’ll try this out at work tomorrow, thank you very much ! Maybe send it as an answer so that I can accept it :)